# Validate xsd attribute specific value occurrence (XSD 1.0)

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes, xsd-validation

Need to validate below xml based on attribute value occurrence?

Validation Rule - Xml should valid only when attribute type="soft" occur at lease once in xml.

This should be valid xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Elements>
        <event>test</event>
        <headers>
            <header>
                <Box id="1234">
                    <page type="soft">

                    </page>                         
                </Box>
            </header>
             <header>
                <Box id="1234">
                    <page type="hard">

                    </page>                         
                </Box>
            </header>
        </headers>
    </Elements>
</Root>
```

This should be invalid xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Elements>
        <event>test</event>
        <headers>
            <header>
                <Box id="1234">
                    <page type="hard">

                    </page> 
                </Box>
            </header>
            <header>
                <Box id="1234">
                    <page type="hard">

                    </page> 
                </Box>
            </header>
        </headers>
    </Elements>
</Root>
```

What should be the xsd for above xml validation?

I got below from internet to use assertion in XSD schema 1.1.

```
<xs:assert test="count(Box\page[@type = 'soft']) > 0"/>
```

How can be achieve this in 1.0?

Comment: You haven't expressed the requirement clearly enough. Is this sample valid or invalid? If it's invalid, why? What are the rules?

Comment: @MichaelKay I have updated details for this question

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved using XSD 1.0.